# Wrap 2D texture around a gameObject with indefinite shape?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to wrap a 2D texture on a gameObject that has curves around it. For example, if I want to wrap a 2D texture on a car, I want it so that it fits properly without any cuts or stretches. Does not matter even if the texture cannot fill the whole car but it should wrap properly. Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: do those meshes have proper UV maps? or do you mean using textures like "stamps" as Decals?

Comment: @mgear yes these meshes have UV maps lets say I want to add a texture on the car that look like reflection.

Comment: reflection is quite a different topic (you can get regular reflections using cubemaps/reflection cubes with standard material for example).. Can you provide example image of what you would like to get working?